# Java ScriptEngine: verifying Invocable.getInterface(Class<?>) returns a real implementation

Tags: java, scriptengine

I'm really excited about incorporating the ScriptEngine into my codebase and plan to use it to build interface implementations on the fly from persisted scripts.

I'm writing up my JUnit test cases for my general implementation of converting script data into a Java interface instance. I seem to be finding out that you don't need to actually implement the whole interface in the script for it to be considered by `Invocable.getInterface(Class<?>)` as an object of that interface. According to the doc for `getInterface` I thought I could count on it returning null if a full implementation was not given:

```
Returns:
An instance of requested interface - null if the requested interface is unavailable, 
i. e. if compiled functions in the ScriptEngine cannot be found matching the ones in the requested interface.
```

Using the `Class<?>` object and calling `isInstance(Object)` on the the result of `Invocable.getInterface(Class<?>)` seems to always return true. I'm guessing there is a conceptual challenge in mapping a dynamic typed script language implementation to the static typed Java interface. However, there is then the problem that if you try to call any unimplemented methods on this object you get a `NoSuchMethodException`.

Here's some snippets of code to help illustrate:

### Test

```
//Data doesnt implement the interface

threwExpectedException = false;

    scriptData = ""; //No actual code, shouldn't be a Queue implementation

try{
    Queue queue = scriptToInterfaceFactory.convertScript(scriptLanguage, scriptData, scriptSignature, Queue.class);
    queue.add(""); //Sanity check. Don't want to get here. Throws NoSuchMethodException
} catch(ScriptNotSupportedException e) { threwExpectedException = true; }

assertTrue(threwExpectedException);
```

### Convert Script Relevant Snippet

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine scriptEngine = mgr.getEngineByName(engineName);

scriptEngine.eval(scriptData);

Invocable inv = (Invocable) scriptEngine;

/* get interfaceClass object from engine. The interface methods
* should be implemented by script functions with the matching name.
* Will return null if it cannot cast to the interface */
Object interfaceObject = inv.getInterface(interfaceClass);

if(interfaceObject == null) {
    log.trace("Interface Object retreived from script is not the same type as the expected interface");
    throw new ScriptNotSupportedException("Interface Object retreived from script is not the same type as the expected interface");
}

return interfaceClass.cast(interfaceObject);
```

### Results

This line  gets hit `queue.add(""); //Sanity check. Don't want to get here. Throws NoSuchMethodException` or if I remove that Sanity check the basic AssertTrue fails because it returns back a Queue object.

## Question

How can one verify that the object pulled from ScriptEngine/Invocable's getInterface(Class) method actually returned a full implementation of the Class interface?

Comment: Have you tried to verify if the object is an instance of one of the known implementing classes found in [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)?

Comment: Elias, that seems a bit too rigid to be general purpose for the need here. I'm not sure I follow why it would be able to be an instance of a class that merely implements the interface, can you clarify? In reality there may not even be any known implementing classes of the given interface.

Comment: @Rich Did you ever figure this out? I am working with this right now and have a hard time finding documentation for `getInterface` other than a few introduction articles that mention it in passing.